# How to use image upload adapters as extra plugins with CKEditor 5 Classic Editor? Or, how to use CKEditor custom builder in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, mern, ckeditor5

I was trying to integrate CKEditor5 in my MERN Stack Application. Its a kind of blog site which requires a fully functioned rich text editor. I integrated the editor and all other things are working fine except the file upload button.
I am using the predefined Classic Editor, which has all the basic functions. But when I click on the Image button to upload an image from local storage, it shows the error :

> filerepository-no-upload-adapter

I tried to add Base64UploadAdapter plugin but then it shows the error :

> Uncaught CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules

Because of this error, I had to remove that plugin, but I still do not have the file upload function.

I also need some other buttons on my text editor, but I am always getting some kind of errors.

I also tried the CKEditor Custom build editor, but when I imported it to my page, it again gives me `ckeditor-duplicated-modules` error. I used the following code for importing:

```
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import Editor from 'ckeditor5-custom-build/build/ckeditor';
```

And yes, I also added the custom builder's folder to my package.json before importing this.

---

I want all the features that I added in my Custom builder, but that's not working in my case. Can anyone please help me with this? Or else, if that is not possible, please give me a solution for file upload which I need for sure, even if I don't get other buttons except the predefined Classic Editor buttons.

But, if there is any way to fix this `ckeditor-duplicated-modules` error and use the Custom build only, that would be the best solution for me..!

Thanks in advance.